# Delete Duplicate entries only if it matches 2 criteria

Tags: google-sheets, duplicates

I have a small project that I'm trying to create in Google Sheets and Forms.

basically, I've created a Time-in and Out Monitoring. The Staff will open a link (Google Form), they will choose their name from the dropdown list, then click submit. Then, on the Google Sheets, It will record the timestamp, Staff name, date and time. Something that looks like [THIS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1E9HLtxqDagxwe073nLhdpOv1VXMDWn5Uyb3gRDIvd2c/edit?usp=sharing).

As you can see, I have duplicate entries (Highlighted rows). What I would like to do is if the Staff name, and the date already exist on that sheet, no duplicate entry should be stored any more. However, it is ok if the Staff Name and date does not match, then it should still be recorded. Currently, I am deleting this duplicates manually, and since I have thousands of rows I am now having a hard time. Would it be possible to automate this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example on how to do this on the Apps Script Samples page called [Tutorial: Removing Duplicate Rows in a Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) which gives you the script:

```
/**
 * Removes duplicate rows from the current sheet.
 */
function removeDuplicates() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = [];
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for (var j in newData) {
      if (row.join() == newData[j].join()) {
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if (!duplicate) {
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}
```

To automate it you can put the function on an [onEdit(e) trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) which will run the script every time it is edited or you can add an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) to run it once a day, once every hour, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Unique formula for this.
If you select both the Staff Name and the Date column it will return the unique combinations and no duplicates.

I made an example [here.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IMmnjZQSP9ffNEKH2N4sg2x3fvg9NpaFqHxzMV-guXk/edit#gid=654075568)

[image: screenshot]